Transition duration does not work for variants with `framer-motion` library
With this code I would expect that on first data change animate will run for 1 second and after that will go to initial state, eg be reverted.
But it stays for a whole time, constantly
const variants = {
  initial: { boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0)' },
  animate: {
    boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 20px 0 #ffc940',
    transition: {
      duration: 1,
      ease: 'easeInOut',
    },
  },
  exit: { boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0)' },
};
const FlashingTableCell: FC<FlashingTableCellProps> = ({ value, type }) => {
  const prevValueRef = useRef(value);
  const [shouldAnimate, setShouldAnimate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (type !== 'button') return;
    prevValueRef.current !== value
      ? setShouldAnimate(true)
      : setShouldAnimate(false);
    prevValueRef.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <motion.td
        key={String(value)}
        variants={variants}
        initial="initial"
        animate={shouldAnimate ? 'animate' : 'initial'}
      >
        {value}
      </motion.td>
      )
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};

Playground link

To achieve desired behavior you can use repeat and repeatType transition properties.
Adjusted variants:
const variants = {
  initial: { boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0)' },
  animate: {
    boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 20px 0 #ffc940',
    transition: {
      duration: 1,
      ease: 'easeInOut',
      repeat: 1,
      repeatType: 'reverse',
    },
  },
  exit: { boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0)' },
};

The thing is that Framer Motion doesn't automatically repeat animations. The initial property is for the animation when your component mounts. The exit property is for when your component is removed from the React tree.

Thanks, it works in the playground. But it looks kind of slower comparing to another animation lib (https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-v9gss5?file=src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev) - visually number is changed and only after that animation started with some delay, eg same 1 sec duration but looks slower
